# Unity game issue with Android 4.1 API 16

Tags: unity-game-engine

I built and ran a very simple 2d game to a Genymotion and  also Android emulator with Android 4.1 API 16 but it crashes while unity support that sdk and API.

AM i missing anything? Any Idea on this issue?

regards
Hassan

Comment: Post your Unity version the crash log

Comment: [As far as I can tell](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidSdkVersions.html), Android 4.1/API 16 is the minimum supported version for Unity. You're going to need to post a crash log, since the problem appears to be with your project, not with Unity itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, where can i find the crash log? I'm newbie!!